# How to parse this JSON response using RETROFIT and populate in Recylcer view Android

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit2

Can anyone kindly tell me my mistake in MainActivty

My JSON Response starts with JSON Array

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": {
      "street": "Douglas Extension",
      "suite": "Suite 847",
      "city": "McKenziehaven",
      "zipcode": "59590-4157",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-68.6102",
        "lng": "-47.0653"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ramiro.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Patricia Lebsack",
    "username": "Karianne",
    "email": "Julianne.OConner@kory.org",
    "address": {
      "street": "Hoeger Mall",
      "suite": "Apt. 692",
      "city": "South Elvis",
      "zipcode": "53919-4257",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "29.4572",
        "lng": "-164.2990"
      }
    },
    "phone": "493-170-9623 x156",
    "website": "kale.biz",
    "company": {
      "name": "Robel-Corkery",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity",
      "bs": "transition cutting-edge web services"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Chelsey Dietrich",
    "username": "Kamren",
    "email": "Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca",
    "address": {
      "street": "Skiles Walks",
      "suite": "Suite 351",
      "city": "Roscoeview",
      "zipcode": "33263",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-31.8129",
        "lng": "62.5342"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(254)954-1289",
    "website": "demarco.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Keebler LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "User-centric fault-tolerant solution",
      "bs": "revolutionize end-to-end systems"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Mrs. Dennis Schulist",
    "username": "Leopoldo_Corkery",
    "email": "Karley_Dach@jasper.info",
    "address": {
      "street": "Norberto Crossing",
      "suite": "Apt. 950",
      "city": "South Christy",
      "zipcode": "23505-1337",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-71.4197",
        "lng": "71.7478"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-477-935-8478 x6430",
    "website": "ola.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Considine-Lockman",
      "catchPhrase": "Synchronised bottom-line interface",
      "bs": "e-enable innovative applications"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Kurtis Weissnat",
    "username": "Elwyn.Skiles",
    "email": "Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Rex Trail",
      "suite": "Suite 280",
      "city": "Howemouth",
      "zipcode": "58804-1099",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.8918",
        "lng": "21.8984"
      }
    },
    "phone": "210.067.6132",
    "website": "elvis.io",
    "company": {
      "name": "Johns Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Configurable multimedia task-force",
      "bs": "generate enterprise e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Nicholas Runolfsdottir V",
    "username": "Maxime_Nienow",
    "email": "Sherwood@rosamond.me",
    "address": {
      "street": "Ellsworth Summit",
      "suite": "Suite 729",
      "city": "Aliyaview",
      "zipcode": "45169",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-14.3990",
        "lng": "-120.7677"
      }
    },
    "phone": "586.493.6943 x140",
    "website": "jacynthe.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Abernathy Group",
      "catchPhrase": "Implemented secondary concept",
      "bs": "e-enable extensible e-tailers"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "name": "Glenna Reichert",
    "username": "Delphine",
    "email": "Chaim_McDermott@dana.io",
    "address": {
      "street": "Dayna Park",
      "suite": "Suite 449",
      "city": "Bartholomebury",
      "zipcode": "76495-3109",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "24.6463",
        "lng": "-168.8889"
      }
    },
    "phone": "(775)976-6794 x41206",
    "website": "conrad.com",
    "company": {
      "name": "Yost and Sons",
      "catchPhrase": "Switchable contextually-based project",
      "bs": "aggregate real-time technologies"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Clementina DuBuque",
    "username": "Moriah.Stanton",
    "email": "Rey.Padberg@karina.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kattie Turnpike",
      "suite": "Suite 198",
      "city": "Lebsackbury",
      "zipcode": "31428-2261",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-38.2386",
        "lng": "57.2232"
      }
    },
    "phone": "024-648-3804",
    "website": "ambrose.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Hoeger LLC",
      "catchPhrase": "Centralized empowering task-force",
      "bs": "target end-to-end models"
    }
  }
]
```

My Adapter class

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<User> ItemsBean;


public UserAdapter(List<User> itemsBean) {
    ItemsBean = itemsBean;

}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.eachrowlayout, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.title.setText(ItemsBean.get(position).getId());
    holder.score.setText(ItemsBean.get(position).getName());
    holder.txtVw_test.setText(ItemsBean.get(position).getCompany().getCatchPhrase());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return ItemsBean.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView title, score, txtVw_test;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_title);
        score = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_count);
        txtVw_test = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtVw_test);
    }
}}
```

My Interface class

```
public interface MyApiEndPointInterface {

    @GET("json/gilde.json")
    Call<List<User>> getPlaceHolderlist();
}
```

My ManiActivity which calls the Retrofit

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/";

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private UserAdapter mAdapter;

List<User> Users;

private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_View);

    OkHttpClient okClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

                    Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Accept","Application/JSON").build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            }).build();


    Retrofit retrofitRef = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


   // RetrofitArrayAPI service = retrofit.create(RetrofitArrayAPI.class);

    MyApiEndPointInterface service = retrofitRef.create(MyApiEndPointInterface.class);



    Call<List<User>> call = service.getPlaceHolderlist();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, retrofit2.Response<List<User>> response) {


            Log.d(TAG,"OnResponse: "+ response.code());

            if(response.isSuccessful()){
            //    Users = new ArrayList<User>();


                List<User> result = response.body();


                mAdapter = new UserAdapter(result);


                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("error");


        }
    });



}}

public class User {
/**
 * id : 1
 * name : Leanne Graham
 * username : Bret
 * email : Sincere@april.biz
 * address : {"street":"Kulas Light","suite":"Apt. 556","city":"Gwenborough","zipcode":"92998-3874","geo":{"lat":"-37.3159","lng":"81.1496"}}
 * phone : 1-770-736-8031 x56442
 * website : hildegard.org
 * company : {"name":"Romaguera-Crona","catchPhrase":"Multi-layered client-server neural-net","bs":"harness real-time e-markets"}
 */

@SerializedName("id")
private int id;
@SerializedName("name")
private String name;
@SerializedName("username")
private String username;
@SerializedName("email")
private String email;
/**
 * street : Kulas Light
 * suite : Apt. 556
 * city : Gwenborough
 * zipcode : 92998-3874
 * geo : {"lat":"-37.3159","lng":"81.1496"}
 */

@SerializedName("address")
private AddressBean address;
@SerializedName("phone")
private String phone;
@SerializedName("website")
private String website;
/**
 * name : Romaguera-Crona
 * catchPhrase : Multi-layered client-server neural-net
 * bs : harness real-time e-markets
 */

@SerializedName("company")
private CompanyBean company;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public AddressBean getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(AddressBean address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getWebsite() {
    return website;
}

public void setWebsite(String website) {
    this.website = website;
}

public CompanyBean getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(CompanyBean company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public static class AddressBean {
    @SerializedName("street")
    private String street;
    @SerializedName("suite")
    private String suite;
    @SerializedName("city")
    private String city;
    @SerializedName("zipcode")
    private String zipcode;
    /**
     * lat : -37.3159
     * lng : 81.1496
     */

    @SerializedName("geo")
    private GeoBean geo;

    public String getStreet() {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getSuite() {
        return suite;
    }

    public void setSuite(String suite) {
        this.suite = suite;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getZipcode() {
        return zipcode;
    }

    public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    public GeoBean getGeo() {
        return geo;
    }

    public void setGeo(GeoBean geo) {
        this.geo = geo;
    }

    public static class GeoBean {
        @SerializedName("lat")
        private String lat;
        @SerializedName("lng")
        private String lng;

        public String getLat() {
            return lat;
        }

        public void setLat(String lat) {
            this.lat = lat;
        }

        public String getLng() {
            return lng;
        }

        public void setLng(String lng) {
            this.lng = lng;
        }
    }
}

public static class CompanyBean {
    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("catchPhrase")
    private String catchPhrase;
    @SerializedName("bs")
    private String bs;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCatchPhrase() {
        return catchPhrase;
    }

    public void setCatchPhrase(String catchPhrase) {
        this.catchPhrase = catchPhrase;
    }

    public String getBs() {
        return bs;
    }

    public void setBs(String bs) {
        this.bs = bs;
    }
}}
```

I am getting error as 404 Response in MainActivity

```
(Log.d(TAG,"OnResponse: "+ response.code());)
```

Comment: I think this issue is not related to your json parsing, it's issue with web service call in retrofit. because 404 is server error.

Comment: try this `@GET("json/gilde")
    Call<List<User>> getPlaceHolderlist();`  . response from server is empty.

Comment: @sushildlh  I have tried the same only but unable to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code, please check your URL, Hope it will help to resolve this issue.

Comment: thanks i checked the URL http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users this one is the correct URL.

Answer (score 0):

i have check your url in post man, this url is not working..[image]

Comment: thanks for your information, Mr . Mohan has found and i have corrected the URL in the above comment.